# Choosing $N$ to prove a sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function. In an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof, would it be acceptable (or good practice) to say, "Choose $N$ such that $f(N)<\epsilon.$"?

Normally (if $g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function) I would say something along the lines of "Choose $N=g(\epsilon)$", and continue on with the standard $n>N\implies n>g(\epsilon)\ldots$

For example, suppose $a\in(0,1)$ and I needed to choose $N$ such that $a^n<\epsilon \space \space\space (\forall n>N)$, so in my proof would it suffice to say "Choose $N$ such that $a^N < \epsilon$. Then $n>N\implies a^n < \epsilon\ldots$"

Comment: I mean, how do you know that is possible? What if $f(x)=1,\;\epsilon=\frac12$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't work, I'm afraid. Consider the following fake proof that $\sin(x)$ converges to $0$ as $x \to \infty$:

> Suppose $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose
>   $$N = \begin{cases}\arcsin(\varepsilon) & \text{if } \varepsilon \le 1 \\ \pi/2 & \text{if } \varepsilon > 1. \end{cases}$$
>   Then, always $\sin(N) \le \varepsilon$, hence (???)
>   $$x > N \implies \sin(x) < \varepsilon.$$

In the specific case of the $a^n$ proof, it sort of works, because $n \mapsto a^n$ is both positive and decreasing, when $a \in (0, 1)$. So, if you know that $a^N < \varepsilon$ and $N < n$, then by definition of increasing, $a^N > a^n$, hence $a^n < \varepsilon$. It's also important that $a^n > 0$, so that $|a^n - 0| = a^n < \varepsilon$.

However, in order to reason in this way, it's important to prove that $n \mapsto a^n$ is indeed decreasing, and show that an $N$ exists such that $a^N < \varepsilon$.